# Shopware 6 error when saving product (Method Not Allowed The requested method PATCH is not allowed for this URL)

Tags: shopware

I just installed Shopware 6. When I try to save a new product it throws a console error for url
https://myshop.com/api/v3/product/b152cac84ddc4aadbecac8e3ba5f65af

```
Method Not Allowed
The requested method PATCH is not allowed for this URL.
```

When I fill in minimum required fields it does save. But when I fill in more fields it throws this error. I did not test it very thoroughly, so I am not sure which fields causes it.

It's stock Shopware 6, I didn't do any custom stuff just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a server configuration issue with Direct Admin where non-standard HTTP methods were blocked by default.

Fixed it with

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build set http_methods GET:HEAD:POST:PUT:DELETE:PATCH
./build rewrite_confs
```

Source: https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=700

Answer (score 1):

When it doesn't work for you (as it didn't for me), try:

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build set http_methods ALL
./build rewrite_confs
```

Source: https://docs.directadmin.com/webservices/apache/customizing.html#enabling-put-and-delete-methods-in-apache-nginx